# Fire CellEndEdit event of DataGridView just when the Enter key is pressed

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have noticed that `CellEndEdit` activates when pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key after editing cell, moving between cells using right or left arrows, or clicking on another cell using the mouse cursor. When I click using the mouse, I get the following error:

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the
>   SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

How can I activate the event `CellEndEdit` of DataGridView only when the Enter key is pressed?

Comment: I have noticed that CellEndEdit activates  when pressing enter after editing cell , moving using arrow leaving the cell right or left, or pressing another cell using mouse. Using mouse, we  get the error" Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."

Comment: What is the overall goal? Your last comment: _”activate the event CellEndEdit of DataGridView only when the Enter key is pressed”_ … --- is not a good idea. If the user edits a grids cell and presses the “enter” key or “tab” key or mouse… what do you want to happen or not happen? Welcome to SO. You may want to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that shows how SO works. In addition, you may want to peruse, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), also if you need [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: thanks .I am not so good in English , maybe that is why  I could not explain good . any way I have solved my question but i need some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` event of a control to detect which key was pressed . Example(This is for only when u are in edit more in datagridview) :

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb)
        {
            tb.KeyDown -= dataGridView1_KeyDown;
            tb.KeyDown += dataGridView1_KeyDown;
        }
   }


private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
{
}
}
```

Comment: when i used the key down event i had to press the enter 2 times to move to the next cell

Comment: which control's keydown r u using ?

Comment: data grid view control

Comment: when u are in edit mode in `DataGridView` Keydown event work just in the second press. I should press `Enter` Key twice when I am in EditMode to fire the keydown event. what I need is, when press Enter, end editing and move to next cell. In short In Editing mode how to catch enter key?

Comment: I do not know i have tried it but something wrong go with ,   if (e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tb)  .

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {

        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            dataGridView1.EndEdit();
            if (dataGridView1 != null &&
                dataGridView1.SelectedCells != null &&
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null)
            {
                if (!(dataGridView1.RowCount == 10 && AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, 9)))
                {
                    bool allEntered = true;
                    int col = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                    int row = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
                    //check if all values in the current row are entered
                    allEntered = AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, row);
                    if (allEntered)
                    {
                        if (row == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value = row + 1;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[0].Value = row + 2;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[row].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1[0, row + 1].ReadOnly = true;
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row + 1].Cells[1];
                            return true;
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1];
                            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
                        }                                          

                    }
                    else if (col == dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("you are in the last cell and not all values are entered,\n enter all values please!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col + 1, row];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);            
    }
    private bool AllRowCellsEntered(DataGridView dataGridView, int row)
    {
        bool allEntered = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value != null)
            {
                int result;
                if (!(int.TryParse(dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value.ToString(), out result)))
                {
                    allEntered = false;
                   // dataGridView.Rows[row].Cells[i].Value = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                allEntered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return allEntered;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1[0, 0].Value = 1;
        dataGridView1[0, 0].ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];

    }
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null))
        {
            if ((dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null))
            {
                string _cellValue = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                int _parsedCellValue = 0;
                {
                    if (!(Int32.TryParse(_cellValue, out _parsedCellValue)))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 10)
        {
            if (AllRowCellsEntered(dataGridView1, dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1))
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                MessageBox.Show("done!");
                // all data entered to datagridview do what do you want!
            }
        }

    }
```

i wrote this and that solve my problem but i don not know i feel it a little long .
any suggestions

Comment: Overriding the `ProcessCmdKey` is probably not the best idea for what you want to do. Example, if the form contains another text box, or any control the user can “type” into will fire this event. This means that when the user presses the “enter” key into some other text box on the form… the code will obligingly update the grid as if the user had pressed the “enter” key in a cell, however in reality it is some other text box on the form. To keep the focus of the key pressed on the grid, you may consider using the `DataGridView.KeyPress` event instead.

Comment: thanks very much for note! I am sorry, but there is something did not understand! I am so frustrated i have just datagridview in the form, so I do not have this problem, but now what is going is that dataGridView1.EndEdit(); did not invoke the event CellEndEdit like before , and the EndCellEdit happens after pressing enter. but all work still work as a result like before. for me it is so strange because i have tried all possibilities when i wrote the code and now it is working in a different way inside.

Comment: the idea that i need enter to be pressed just one time (when i am in editing mode) to end edit ,move to next cell if it is not the last  column , or if all valued have been entered (no matter where is editing cell) were integer(which i check it in the CellEndEdit by invoke it by dataGridView1.EndEdit();   add new row.